# Boat crossing flowing river

Tags: vectors

A boat can travel at $3.5 m/s$ in still water. A river is $80 m$ wide and the water flows at $2 m/s$. Calculate

1. the shortest time to cross the river and the distance down stream that the boat is carried
2. the course that must be set to cross the river to a point exactly opposite to the starting point and the time taken for the crossing.

ANSWER:

$1$. time taken $=(80/ 3.5) = 22.9 s$
   distance down the stream $= 22.9\times2 = 45.8 m$

I'm having difficulties in doing the second part..can you please help me? thank you

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, draw a right angled triangle with $3.5$ as the hypotenuse, then the speed of the boat relative to the earth is $$\sqrt(3.5^2-2^2)$$

Can you do the rest?

Comment: @ David Quinn thnx a lot

Comment: @ user247327 ty

Answer (score 0):

Set up a coordinate system so that the $x$-axis is across the river and the $y$-axis is up the river.  Then the velocity vector, relative to the water, of the boat aimed directly across the river is $\langle3.5, 0\rangle$  and the velocity vector of the water is $\langle0, 2\rangle$  The resultant velocity vector is $\langle3.5, 2\rangle$.  The time required to cross the $80 m$ river is $\frac{80}{3.5}=22.86$ seconds (approximately).  In that time, the boat will have gone $2(22.86)= 45.71$ meters down the river.

In order to arrive at a point directly across the river the boat must have a velocity vector $\langle u, v\rangle$ such that $\langle u, v\rangle+ \langle0, 2\rangle= \langle u, v+ 2\rangle= \langle\frac{80}{t}, 0\rangle$ and $\sqrt{u^2+ v^2}= 3.5$.  Since $v+ 2= 0, v= -2$ so $\sqrt{u^2+ v^2}= \sqrt{u^2+ 4}= 3.5$.  Squaring both sides, $u^2+ 4= 12.25, u^2= 8.25$ so $u= 2.87 m/s$ approximately.

The velocity vector is $\langle 2.87, 2\rangle$ and the time to cross is given by $u= 2.87= 80/t, t= 80/2.87= 27.85$ seconds.

Comment: Please take a look at [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for future posts.